# build PHP option list whilst using AES_DECRYPT.

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to build a option list from a database, when selected it looks up all items issued from separate databases. This worked well until i had to decrypted with `AES_DECRYPT()`. The value is stored so the look up still works but no visible names.

```
<form>
            Select a name and will list all items currently issued to that person. Press return to return an item.      
        <select id="list" name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
    <?php
    $servername = "";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "";
    $aeskey = 'key';
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
        $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, AES_DECRYPT(Fname,"'.$aeskey.'"),AES_DECRYPT(Sname,"'.$aeskey.'") FROM  `name` ORDER BY  `Sname` DESC ');
    $stmt->execute();
       while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option id ="'.$row['id'].'"value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['Fname']." ".$row['Sname'].'</option>';
       }
     ?>
 </select> 
            <div id="textt"><b>items listed here.</b></div>
            <br />
        </form>
```

if i change the `$stmt = $pdo->prepare` to 
`('SELECT id, Fname, Sname FROM  'name' ORDER BY  'Sname' DESC ');` it works fine however all the names are encrypted. I have tried moving the AES_DECRTYPT to inside the while statement with no luck. I have also checked the select statement in phpMyAdmin and it worked fine. 
Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer by searching loads of threads on here and combining answers.

```
 <form>
    Select a name and will list all items currently issued to that person. Press return to return an item.      
    <select id="list" name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
    <?php
    $servername = "";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "";
    $aeskey = 'key';
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
        $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, CAST(AES_DECRYPT(Fname,"'.$aeskey.'")
    AS CHAR(50)) fname_decrypt,CAST(AES_DECRYPT(Sname,"'.$aeskey.'")AS CHAR (50)) sname_decrypt FROM  `name` ORDER BY  `Sname` DESC ');
    $stmt->execute();
       while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option id ="'.$row['id'].'"value="'.$row['id'].'">'.
    $row['Fname_decrypt']." ".$row['Sname_decrypt'].'</option>';
       }
     ?>
 </select> 
            <div id="text"><b>items listed here.</b></div>
            <br />
        </form>
```

by using `CAST(AES_DECRYPT(fname,"'.$aeskey.'")AS CHAR(50)) fname_decrypt` then looking up `$row['fname_decrypt'`] i get the results wanted.

Comment: $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT AES_DECRYPT(name, "'.$fuzzyFiKey.'") AS name, AES_DECRYPT(email, "'.$fuzzyFiKey.'") AS email.... works for me.